# Android element layout: with XML or in code?

Tags: android, layout

How easily can you layout elements in Android programmatically, and is this a practical alternative to using the XML / code split typically used in Android?

Coming from an iOS background, where similarly you can connect UI elements in a storyboard with code in the body files, I've found that creating all elements in code itself offers greater overview and reduces coding time. There's also a lot less toggling between the two files.

Android seems to place greater importance on the use of XML for layout than Apple does for storyboards, and I'm wondering if it's a bridge too far to force element creation into the activities themselves.

I get that to a limited extent the question refers to coding style (thereby inviting off-topic discussion), but not exclusively so and insofar it influences UX (and maybe performance), it's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `xml` is easier than using java and more flexible to control : example of `Button` inside `LinearLayout`

```
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("My Button");
button.setWidth(100);// in pixel not recommended
button.setHeight(100);
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
button.setX(100);
button.setY(100);
button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 20);// to convert into sp
LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
container.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
container.addView(button);
```

it may take 15min of coding will using xml is just drag and drop and using the `xml Editor`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using layout files let you better manage the UI as compared to adding them programmatically which would include the aligning the views from all the sides and setting params and rules. This would make java file more cumbersome. Better approach would be keeping the two separate unless required.

Comment: I'm getting the impression that .java files are a lot less verbose than objective-c .m files. Also that element layout is more akin to floating elements in web design, or AutoLayout + Storyboards in iOS. If there is no difference in performance / UX, it's a coding preference.

Comment: Yah but layout files keep your code more cleaner and understandable.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and used to work like that by splitting the UI and code up, and sure enough if you're working with designers and just need to hook into their UI it might be better, but found that I had a better understanding of what was going on by packing them all into the body file.

Comment: Yah, its solely than a developer preference :)